# Flow not finding module from my own file?

Tags: react-native, flowtype

I have this line in my code:

```
import { GoogleMapsApiKey } from "../../.secrets";
```

Flow is complaining that it can't resolve the module. The file is definitely there, and the import is working (`GoogleMapsApiKey` isn't giving me any problems).

I've found answers with `flow-typed` for node modules, and I suppose I could stub this as well, but that seems dumb since this file is *there*.

`.secrets.js` is in `.gitignore`, that doesn't make a difference, does it?

Comment: Maybe it's outside the root folder? I'd double check the flow config.

Comment: The `secrets` file is in the root folder, and as I said, the file I'm using it in finds it fine. What would I check in the flow config?

Comment: Maybe it has problems detecting the [ending correctly](https://flow.org/en/docs/config/options/#toc-module-file-ext-string)? Maybe it is listed in the `ignore` part of the flow config?

Comment: Does it work if you rename the file without a leading dot? I wonder if Flow is somehow treating it differently.